# How can I extract tokens from the current URL using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Given an URL such as `/abc.html#variable1`, I want to capture the `variable1` part to determine a given user's "virtual page" when working with JavaScript (jQuery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you don't need at all jquery, just use

to get the url use

```
var the_link = document.location
```

to get just the hash part of the url (the text after #) use

```
var the_hash = document.location.hash
```

to get the GET variables you can use

```
var get_vars = document.location.search
```

Comment: Thanks it works but i am linking from same page for example i have abc.html#varible1 link on abc.html. In this case it does not catch click event vice verse if i go to abc.html#varible1 via browser address line or from another page it works. How can i fix that ? Thanks

Comment: @mTuran: Maybe you should check this page http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/docs/files/jquery-ba-hashchange-js.html

Answer (score 0):

Examine the `window.location.hash`. Not jQuery specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.hash` to get the value after the `#` sign.

You can find some information on the topic [here](http://programming.top54u.com/post/Javascript-Location-Hash-with-Example.aspx).  And within the context of unique URLs for AJAX, you can check out this [extensive article](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Unique_URLs).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are asking for, but the way to retrieve the page's url is:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
```

It is really javascript, no jQuery involved.
If you want to addd some jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
});
```

Hope it helps.